# rewrite rules don't work on IIS

Tags: php, iis, yii, url-rewriting

I'm doing `php` programming on `IIS`. The php framework I'm using is Yii. to hide `index.php` and using friendly URL I enabled `urlManager` on `config.php` file. my problem is that when I try navigate to my controllers server returns error 404. I think there is something wrong in rewriting rules but I'm not familiar with `IIS` web server. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please read the IIS documentation for an answer.

Comment: @Matt would you give me link?

Comment: This is easily found with a simple google search. Please put in some effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my question. this is the original rules in `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and here is the its translation in `web.config` format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule> 
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```